# Why is my console not logging search input?

Tags: javascript, html

New to web programming, I am trying to log HTML search query to the console after saving it to a variable. For some reason, when I execute the search, nothing is logging to my browser's inspect console. Is there a piece that I am missing here?

Here is my HTML form

```
    <form id="searchForm">
      <input type="search" id="userInput" class="search" placeholder="Search" />
      <input type="submit" onclick="window.location.href='www/results.html';" id="subButton" value="Search" />
    </form>
```

I have a file called input.js that contains a function that should log my input.

```
function getInput() {
  const userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').nodeValue;
  console.log(userInput);
  return userInput;
}
```

I also have the main script that call getInput.

```
const subButton = document.getElementById('subButton');
if (subButton) {
  subButton.addEventListener('click', getInput, false);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the value of input field. You should use `value` instead of `nodevalue`. The following code would do the job -

```js
function getInput() {
  const userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
  console.log(userInput);
  return userInput;
}

const subButton = document.getElementById('subButton');
if (subButton) {
  subButton.addEventListener('click', getInput, false);
}
```

```html
<form id="searchForm">
  <input type="search" id="userInput" class="search" placeholder="Search" />
  <input type="submit" onclick="window.location.href='www/results.html';" id="subButton" value="Search" />
</form>
```

`nodeValue` is used to get the value of a node which is different that what you are trying to get. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue) and there's also a good explanation on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43809678/13602076) .

Comment: thank you, I did that, and I see that your snippet logs to the console. For some reason, my console still does not show the text I enter the bar. Am I sourcing the script correctly in my HTML file? This is the code that I have for this as of now:                                            
<script src="www/scripts/input.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: @ianwt It must be some error/typo in including the scripts into your file. Check again and see if they are correct and working

Comment: I had to put the script at the end of the HTML file so that everything loaded :) @Abhishek